# How can one detect ACC, PCC or any other medial cortical activity with MEG or EEG if it's inside the brain?

Tags: methodology, eeg, meg

Been reading some research involving various brain imaging techniques and it's not my strong point. Really, if the electrodes or SQUIDS measure surface activity, how does one measure what's going on in the medial cortices?

Comment: I don't have time to respond right now, but we can used advance statistical modelling, often referred to as source analysis, which can be applied to diffused activity. Its accuracy is not as strong as neocortical activity however the techniques have improved markedly over the last few years as our processing power has improved along with the statistical modelling process. Please see the linked article. If I get time later I will write a reply...https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fneur.2019.00325/full#h7 hope that helps for now

Comment: Thank you! I will consult with the article and wait for your reply as well!